# How to pass properties from one method to another?

Tags: php

I'm trying to understand the concept I'm trying to accomplish, I don't even know what it's called so please bear with me. I can only show you what I'm trying to accomplish.

I'm creating a class that will convert measurements from one to another.

```
class UnitConverter {

    public $value;

    /**
    * Amount to convert
    */
    public function convert($value){
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    /**
    * convert value from what unit
    */
    public function from($from){
        // cup to tablespoon
    }

    /**
    * converting value to specific unit
    */
    public function to($to){

    }
}
```

This is basically much how I'd like to do so instead of calling each method individually.

```
$var = new UnitConverter();
$var->convert(1)->from('pounds')->to('tbsp');
```

Comment: I'm curious how you propose to convert from a unit of weight to a unit of volume.

Comment: If you're wondering what calling methods one after the other is called, the industry term is [Method Chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining), though another industry term is "train wreck" - I'll let you ponder why :)

Comment: @Sammitch there are valid measurement conversions for lb-tbsp when you know the ingredient being measured (e.g. water, sugar)

Comment: @e_i_pi `s/ingredient/matter density/` but yes :P

Comment: I'd argue that your approach is wrong. You're not stipulating what you're converting, and method chaining has a very specific use. Normally a from/to conversion function would take both arguments (`$from`, `$to`) and then return a value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While method chaining is *a thing*, I don't think that it's at all suitable for what you're doing.

Instead I would suggest a more compositional approach like below.

```
class Unit {
    protected $type; // the type of unit, to prevent mismatches, eg: volume
    protected $name; // the unit name, eg: mL
    protected $rate; // the conversion rate between the stated unit and the Base unit

    public function __construct(string $name, string $type, float $rate) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->type = $type;
        $this->rate = $rate;
    }

    // ToDo: put 'get*()' methods here [I am lazy]
}

class UnitConverter {
    public static function convert(float $amount, Unit $from, Unit $to) {
        if( $from->getType() !== $to->getType() ) {
            throw new Exception('Unit type mismatch, cannot convert!');
        }
        return $amount * $from->getRate() / $to->getRate();
    }
}

$ml  = new Unit( 'mL', 'volume', 1);
$tsp = new Unit('tsp', 'volume', 5.91939);
$gal = new Unit('gal', 'volume', 3785.41);

UnitConverter::convert(1000,  $ml, $gal); // should return 0.2641721769
UnitConverter::convert(1,    $gal, $tsp); // should return 639.4932585959
```

and you can build more functionality around it, such as:

```
class Quantity {
    protected $amount;
    protected $unit;

    public function(float $amount, Unit $unit) {
        $this->amount = $amount;
        $this->unit = $unit;
    }

    public function convert(Unit $new_unit) {
        return new $this(
            UnitConverter::convert($this->amount, $this->unit, $new_unit),
            $new_unit
        )
    }
}

$ingredient = new Quantity(2.5, $gal);
$ingredient_metric = $ingredient->convert($ml);
```

Comment: Excellent solution, I was planning posting something pretty similar, but I took a sabbatical down the beach

Comment: That's much more dynamic than how I wanted to accomplish it, took a while to get to this because I was figuring out some stuff. Thank you for the further explanation too.

Answer (score 3):

> How to pass properties from one method to another?

Methods don't have properties, they have parameters (stuff you put in brackets when you invoke them) and return values. Objects have properties. Sammitch's answer shows how to assign parameters to properties in the constructor.

> $var->convert(1)->from('pounds')->to('tbsp');

The above is a legitimate syntax construct (assuming the methods are properly implemented) known as method chaining.

In order to implement it, the `convert($amount)` method must return a reference to `$var` - specifically the method would end with `return $this;` in the class. Similarly the `from($measure)` needs to return $this.

It is a question of semantic as to what the `to()` method returns, but the convention is to use method chaining in *all* public methods or none of them. So to retrieve the result you would need to add a method which takes an argument by reference (rather than by value), e.g.

```
 protected $amount;
 protected $fromMeasure;
 protected $toMeasure;

 public function convert($amount)
 {
    if (is_numeric($amount)) {
       $this->amount=$amount;
    } else {
       throw new Exception('convert called with non-numeric value');
    }
    return $this;
 }
 public function from($fromMeasure)
 {
    if ($this->is_valid_measure($fromMeasure)) {
       $this->fromMeasure=$fromMeasure;
    } else {
       throw new Exception("Unknown measurement type $fromMeasure");
    } 
    return $this;
 }
 public function getResult(&$result)
 {
    if (!$this->is_valid_conversion()) {
         throw new Exception("Can't convert " 
            . this->fromMeasure . " to "
            . $this->toMeasure);
         return $this;
    }
    if (is_numeric($this->amount) && $this->fromMeasure && $this->toMeasure) { 
        $result=$this->calculate();
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Object calc invoked before primed');
    }
    return $this;
 }
 protected function calculate()
 {
     ... include some calculation....
     return $calculatedResult;
     // note that method does not return $this AND IS NOT PUBLIC
 }
```

(note the above is deliberately incomplete and may expose your system to code injection via logging)

Comment: Hah. I was just ruminating on this question a bit more and came back to basically write this very thing, but with somewhat more huffiness about not liking chaining. :P

Comment: Also worth noting that objects that use chaining like this should be single-use, since if you're not perfectly mindful of cleaning up between executions your object state can and *will* be polluted.